# How to fire Javascript code to be the last, when all the HTML/CSS and Javascript Codes are fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been updating a client website which only allows me to add script and style codes on limited areas.  I've used FF "Inspect Elements" and can view the codes and can do tests using Edit CSS of the web dev add-on tool.  However, I could not get to style the codes I see using a simple Javascript code.  When I checked the code using "View Source", the  code that i need to edit is not showing.

To get an idea of what I'm doing, here's a similar code.  Objective is to style the DIV with green border when an img src contains the string "white":

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="cropImg" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/f00&text=red" alt="red">
    <img class="cropImg" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/fff&text=white" alt="white">
    <img class="cropImg" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/00f&text=blue" alt="blue">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var xColour = $("img[src*='white']");
    xColour.css('border','5px solid green');
});
```

I have also created a JSFiddle for quick viewing ==>
http://jsfiddle.net/philcyb/q5cqomto/

QUESTION:
Is there a way to fire my inserted Javascript as the last one to be fired?
Or if my question is not relevant, any thoughts shared is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't have much to add other than I think the dom is fired in order from top to bottom, I'd just put your "last" script as close to the body close tag as possible...

Comment: @quid - thanks. I'm also thinking of setTimeOut method (though I haven't really tried), but perhaps there are other better ways than this one.

Comment: Put to `$(document).ready()` is late enough. Also I suggest using `box-shadow` over `border`, for better alignment, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/myst/q5cqomto/1/

Comment: And by the way, are you saying add border to DIV, or the IMG?

Comment: @LeoDeng - thanks. border or shadow anywhere in DIV or IMG is ok. My question is more of the the javascript executed as the very most final last end one (if i would describe it).

Comment: Well, `$(window).on('load', function() {...})` is even later than `$(document).ready()`, after all external resources (including images) are ready. However, if any script is requesting resources asynchronously, it's still not trustable.

Comment: If there are multiple document ready handlers jQuery will fire them in the order they were bound, so using that on its own in your code is not enough if you can't control other scripts on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code to achieve what you want

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
```

// code here
});

Comment: did you mean use this code instead of the "$(document).ready(function(){" code?

Comment: yes. Code inside this block will be executed once page is loaded completely